# What do we call words that have vernacular meanings at odds with specialized meaning, e.g. "imply"

Tags: terminology

A commonly quoted caveat when seeing news reports or scientific data is that "Correlation does not imply causation".

While this is true in the logical sense of *imply,* i.e. to be sufficient evidence of, it is misleading and somewhat illogical if reader assumes the vernacular definition of *imply,* i.e. to suggest.

Often correlation **does** suggest causation, or at least should suggest further investigation in that direction to dismiss a causal link.

There are probably many examples of phrases or words that often have contrary meanings because the everyday usage of the term and the technical meaning of the term have diverged. Is there a term for such words  or instances?

Comment: *peruse* comes to mind.

Comment: Theory.  The common use is almost the exact opposite of the technical use.   I cringe when I hear someone say things like, "Well, that's just a theory."

Comment: Almost **any** word that has one or more technical meanings but is also used non-technically falls into this category - *proof*, *truth*, *liquid*, *infinite*, *egg*, *fruit*, *berry*, *flower*, *space*, *time*... The question is far too broad.

Comment: I've adjusted the question to remove the request for a list of such words, concentrating on the term of art.

Comment: Consider _misused_ (or _colloquially misused_) words. I'm not sure if there is a more specific term for these words. [_Wikipedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_commonly_misused_English_words) has an article called _List of commonly misused words_ but it also includes homonyms or pairs of similarly spelled words that are often confused. [_Livescience_](https://www.livescience.com/28347-most-misused-science-words.html) has an article called _7 misused science words_.

Comment: Would *polysemy* work or are you looking for a more specific term?

Comment: *[Vernacular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernacular_architecture)* is probably a better example than *imply*.

Answer (score 0):

Layman’s terms, "in words that someone who is not an expert can understand" macmillandictionary.com, is frequently used to differentiate between technical meaning and common usage.

Comment: I believe this does not answer the question. You should consider putting this as a comment.